# Is there any ETL tool for any Smalltalk dialect?

Tags: smalltalk, etl

...like Talend for Java, for instance, but that allows to implement processes programatically.

Multiple data sources, orchestration, calculated fields, pivot tables are some of the features I would like to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly 5 years later it is time to revisit this answer. Pharo and Moose support 64 bits. The garbage collector is not yet up to handling very large heaps, the incremental collector to avoid large pauses is in active development now. If the work is partitionable, use a solution like [ImageWorker](https://github.com/pharo-contributions/ImageWorker) to use multiple cores with all data in one image, or [TelePharo](https://github.com/pharo-ide/TelePharo) to remote control multiple images. Perhaps use [MQTT](https://github.com/LabWare/MQTT-broker) to integrate. For visualization there are Roassal2 and 3 or the whole [GToolkit](https://github.com/feenkcom/gtoolkit)

Comment: This is great. If I had to do a project like this again, I'll follow this approach. Thank you Stephan!

Answer (score 3):

We've build on top of Moose for a ERP data conversion project. Works well with smaller amounts of data (that fit in a 32-bit image). In ETL with multiple sources, just use an image for each input stream/step, connect them together through files or sockets. The visualization was important for us. It allowed the domain experts to steer the process. Short feedback loop was essential.